# how to detect vue data passed to vuex state and check for it

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

i'm making a playlist and i add my songs to it with vuex and ther is no problem. but i don't know how to detect it, if this data added to state or not?

this is my vuex:

```
export const state = () => ({
  playlist: []

});

export const mutations = {
  addToPlaylist(state, val) {
    state.playlist.push(val);
  }
};

export const getters = {
  playlistItems: state => state.playlist
};
```

and i get my playlist items like this in created hook:

```
 this.playlist = this.$store.getters.playlistItems;
      this.$store.watch(
        (state) => {
          return this.$store.getters.playlistItems
        },
        (val) => {
          this.playlist = val;
        }
      )
```

these code works and there is no problem, but i don't know how to detect it.

my data is like this:

```
musics: [
          {
            id: 1,
            cover: require('~/assets/images/cover/music/ali_zand_vakili_jadeh_shab.jpg'),
            title: 'جاده شب',
            artist: 'علی زند وکیلی',
            source: 'http://media.mtvpersian.net/2019/Mar/21/Ali%20Zand%20Vakili%20-%20Jadeh%20Shab.mp3'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            cover: require('~/assets/images/cover/music/amin_hayaei_divoone_misazi.jpg'),
            title: 'دیوونه میسازی',
            artist: 'امین حیایی',
            source: 'https://cdnmrtehran.ir/media/mp3s_128/Amin_Hayaei/Singles/amin_hayaei_divoone_misazi.mp3'
          },
        ],
```

i want to change icon if this data added or not for all items
each item has icon

thanks

Comment: Once you can get the list of itens and you have an item, you can create a method that just test something like includes or find, called for example isInList(item) and returning a boolean, right?

Comment: @MatheusValenza can you show me an example? i'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can make a function to check if selected music with id already in list.

```
isAlreadyAdded(id, arr) {
  let is_in = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].id === id) {
       is_in = true;
       break;
    }
  }
  return is_in;
}
```